# Program does not take input from user to loop itself again.

Tags: c, mpi

I have this code down here and it working for calculating but it does not take the input of the user to do the loop again and calculate for the user again or cancel.  the function is near the end with if(rank == 0) { ... }.  I need help figure out what am I missing

```
#include <math.h> //include files
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"

void printit()
{
   printf("\n*********************************\n");
   printf("Welcome to the pi calculator!\n");
   printf("Programmer: K. Spry\n");
   printf("You set the number of divisions\n");
   printf("for estimating the integral: \n\tf(x)=4/(1+x^2)");
   printf("\n");
   printf("*********************************\n");
}                      //end printit
                                                          //function prototypes

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   double actual_pi = 3.141592653589793238462643;
                                                                               //for comparison later
   int n, rank, num_proc, i;
   double temp_pi, calc_pi, int_size, part_sum, x;
   char response = 'y';
   MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
   MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &num_proc);
   if (rank == 0)
   {
        printit();
   }             /* I am root node, print out welcome */

   while (response == 'y')
   {
      if (rank == 0)
      {            /*I am root node*/
         printf("__________________________________\n");
         printf("\nEnter the number of intervals: (0 will exit)\n");
         n = fgetc(stdin);
      }

      else
      {
         int_size = 1.0 / (double) n;                  //calcs interval size
         part_sum = 0.0;

         for (i = rank * n / num_proc; i <= (rank + 1)* n / num_proc; i += 1)
         {                                                         //calcs partial sums
              x = int_size * ((double)i - 0.5);
              part_sum += (4.0 / (1.0 + x*x));
         }
         temp_pi = int_size * part_sum;
                                       //collects all partial sums computes pi

         MPI_Reduce(&temp_pi,&calc_pi, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
         if (rank == 0)
         {                                                     /*I am server*/
            printf("pi is approximately %f", calc_pi);
            printf(". Error is %f", fabs(calc_pi - actual_pi));
            printf("\n");
            printf("_______________________________________");
            printf("\n");
         }
      }                                                                        //end else
     if (rank == 0)
     { /*I am root node*/
        printf("\nCompute with new intervals? (y/n)\n");
        response = fgetc(stdin);
     }
   } //end while
   MPI_Finalize();                                             //terminate MPI
   return 0;
}
```

The problem I have is with the if inside the loop while that ask user to Compute with new intervals and user will input Y or N to response.  The problem is when users do input, it stop working and never loop.

Comment: I think `fgetc(stdin)` leaves the newline character in the buffer.

Comment: Should I change fgetc to fgets or gets ?

Comment: the function: `fgetc()` returns an `int`, not a char.

Comment: OT:  `gets()` has been depreciated for years and completely removed from the latest C standard.  I.E. NEVER use `gets()`

Comment: Hello, so now I replace the response = fgetc(stdin) with scanf("%c", response).  It give me the error of segmentation fault (11)

Comment: Your root process never communicates `response` or `n`.  Thus, they are all uninitialized garbage on the other ranks.  Your output condition is also `rank != 0 && rank == 0`

Comment: **all** the ranks must invoke `MPI_Reduce(..., MPI_COMM_WORLD)` (and they should likely participate to the computation too)

Answer (score 0):

It behave as it should from what you coded :-).
The comment from ptb is the answer of your question.... But lets do it :-).

```
while (response == 'y')
{
  if (rank == 0)
  {  /*I am root node*/
     printf("__________________________________\n");
     printf("\nEnter the number of intervals: (0 will exit)\n");
     n = fgetc(stdin);
  }
  /* here we have to: broadcast to all processes the value of response
     in fact all processes have to wait that root get the new value and then
     get this value from the root. Fortunately MPI_Broadcast is a blocking
     opperation, so no MPI_Barrier are needed...*/
  MPI_Bcast(&n,1,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  /* then your computation is done by every processes (in fact in your interval
     boundaries you indeed take that process 0 has the first interval... i am not 
     sure your math a correct, I did not check them) */

  int_size = 1.0 / (double) n;                  //calcs interval size
  part_sum = 0.0;

  for (i = rank * n / num_proc; i <= (rank + 1)* n / num_proc; i += 1)
  {                                                         //calcs partial sums
    x = int_size * ((double)i - 0.5);
    part_sum += (4.0 / (1.0 + x*x));
  }
  temp_pi = int_size * part_sum;
  //collects all partial sums computes pi
  MPI_Reduce(&temp_pi,&calc_pi, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  if (rank == 0)
  {                                                     /*I am server*/
     printf("pi is approximately %f", calc_pi);
     printf(". Error is %f", fabs(calc_pi - actual_pi));
     printf("\n");
     printf("_______________________________________");
     printf("\n");
  }

  if (rank == 0)
  { /*I am root node*/
    printf("\nCompute with new intervals? (y/n)\n");
    response = fgetc(stdin);
  }
  /* here we have to: broadcast to all processes the value of response
     in fact all processes have to wait that root get the new value and then
     get this value from the root. Fortunately MPI_Broadcast is a blocking
     opperation, so no MPI_Barrier are needed..., lol same than with n...*/
  MPI_Bcast(&response,1,MPI_CHAR,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);    
} //end while
```

I did not try to compile... so there is maybe some typos...